# How do I INSERT if a row does not already exist with four zillion concurrent threads?

Tags: sql, concurrency, db2, persistence, mybatis

I need to do the following in four zillion threads at the same time (well, probably closer to 2 threads, but either way...): If such-and-such does not exist, insert it.

Currently, the application says:

```
select rows from the db
if row count == 0,
    do some stuff
    insert a row
```

I have a situation where this is run in 2 separate threads at the same time. This way, the 2 threads may (and in fact do every time so far) each check for existing rows before either thread inserts rows; therefore we have duplicate rows. This is bad.

All the algorithms I can think of fall short one way or another.

For example, if I do this:

```
open tx
insert a row
select rows
if row count > 2, rollback
else commit
```

when the transaction uses `READ_COMMITTED` isolation, then one thread won't see another thread's inserted rows, and duplicates are possible. With `READ_UNCOMMITTED` isolation, each thread may see the other thread's rows and both will rollback. I think I'll have the same problem if I use a `MERGE` statement instead of inserting then selecting (or vice versa).

Is there an algorithm to use to guarantee that exactly 1 row will be inserted when the above algorithm is executed concurrently? FWIW, I'm using DB2, mybatis, and xml-based tx management with Spring, but I'll gladly translate from something else if possible.

I'm a newbie when it comes to concurrency, so if this question reveals ignorance remedied by a book or article you know of, please share.

EDIT:

The insert statement above is to lazily grant users something iff they don't have it.  In this case, a uniqueness constraint would be appropriate.  Elsewhere in the app, however, it would not be appropriate.  :(

I'll make the example a bit more concrete soon so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Is the `INSERT` the only (necessary) thing in the transaction?  It's possible to write them so that they 'fail' (doesn't insert a row) if it already exists (which may _still_ fall afoul of concurrency issues, I haven't investigated this enough in a highly concurrent environment).  Write it that way, slap `NO COMMIT` on it, and you _may_ be okay.  Otherwise, yeah, the unique constraint would probably be good regardless...

Comment: The insert is the purpose of the statement, but it should not insert if another thread inserts.  A uniqueness constraint would solve the problem, but cause another: We need to allow >1 row with the given criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution we could find was to issue the "insert if no records meeting criteria exist" command in a serializable transaction.  The SQL itself could be anything that inserts records if none meeting certain criteria exist (e.g. MERGE would work).  In this scenario, once one thread checks for the existence of a row meeting the criteria of the selected statement, no other thread may insert anything meeting that criteria until the tx is completed.  For performance, we opened a new tx just for the merge operation and committed immediately upon completion.

We tested this solution with DB2 and Oracle with success.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a uniqueness constraint and use ReadCommitted. that way if the second thread tries to insert a dup, it gets rolled back, but the initial insert works.

Comment: The plot thickens: I'm inserting a row in table A where T.x=1.  A uniqueness constraint on T.y is appropriate iff x=1, but not if x=0 (which is the case for other rows).  Is there a way to enforce uniqueness for T.y iff x=1?

Comment: perhaps with a trigger, but thats getting a bit complicated.

Comment: @FrankThomas can you please elaborate how to use read committed in this case?

Comment: Its not ReadCommitted that makes this solution work, but the uniqueness constraint. ReadCommitted is a threadsafe isolation level, so when combined with a Uniqueness constraint, whatever thread ge5ts in first wins, and the second one fails, without producing a duplicate row. Other, less safe isolation levels may or may not work the same way when dealing with conflicting inserts.

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar. Because we don't want to lock the tables, we use optimistic concurrency and uniqueness constraints.

1. The first condition that will burn you due to concurrency is inserting the same thing twice in two separate threads. The solution as mentioned by others is to included a uniqueness contraints in your schema. This can be tricky if you have a compound constraint where columns are nullable. See this raging argument: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173 So you may need to have an extra column for the uniqueness contraint.
2. The second condition that potentially burns you is you need to make an update to the data (such as incrementing by one or something). In this case, we use optimistic concurrency as supported by hibernate with it's row versioning. Check out http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic. Not sure if mybatis has something similar, but you can write the same thing manually. If your threads do have a collision, one will fail. For us, we need both to succeed, so if we have a collision, the failing thread will retry the operation (by re-reading, re-processing and re-writing the data). In this case, we do something similar to the way Ethernet works (or any other collision based protocol/operation), i.e. try, if fail, backoff somehow and try again.

HTH.

Comment: A uniqueness constraint won't work because we allow > 1 row per user when the user takes action to make that happen, but the first row must be created lazily and automatically, and only the first row is allowed to be created w/o the user's input.

Comment: As for your second point, I don't recall if we have optimistic locking in place, but update collisions are not an issue; only inserting duplicates is an issue.

Comment: Guess I need a little bit more info. Still sounds like you can design a schema that allows for a uniqueness constraint. If you don't want this, you'll need to enable table locking, which has performance issues, and wrap everything in a single TX. I'm not sure how you do this in DB2 though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the

```
MERGE
```

SQL statement.   It has the ability to insert a row that doesn't exist in a single statement.

Comment: What if this happens?:
1. Thread 1 opens a tx and merges.
2. Thread 2 opens a tx, merges, and commits.
3. Thread 1 commits.

AFAIK, this will give us duplicate rows, unless we use read uncommitted isolation on the tx's.  Even then, do we know that multiple threads cannot perform a merge at the same time, such that both insert and neither "sees" the other's inserted row?

Comment: Interestingly, even when using a new read-uncommitted tx w/ DB2, duplicate rows are inserted.  I told a DBA this and he was puzzled.  I'm going to try "INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXIST ..." even though it may exhibit the same problem for the same unknown reason.

Comment: If you want to enforce uniqueness, it's best to use an index, and not rely on which isolation level the application uses.  Have a look at the lock matrix for merge.

Comment: can you please elaborate on using an index to enforce uniqueness?  Please note, as mentioned above, that we must allow duplicate rows, but forbid duplicate rows inserted by this one routine: This routine automatically inserts 1 row if-and-only-if the user has 0 rows, but users may add more themselves later.